# swagger editor does not generate correct request for file upload

Tags: file, file-upload, swagger-editor

I am using Swagger editor to build a post request to upload a file. My swagger json file is defined as follows.

```
swagger: '2.0'
info:
  version: 0.0.0
  title: '<enter your title>'
host: 'localhost:11235'
paths:
  /form/upload:
    post:
      description: |
         Post files.
      consumes:
        - multipart/form-data
      produces:
        - application/octet-stream
      parameters:
        - name: file
          in: formData
          description: upload file
          required: true
          type: file
        - name: text
          description: additional info
          in: formData
          type: string
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Successful response
          schema:
            type: file
```

Then on the right side of the editor. I click the Try this operation. I select a file. The constructed request looks like this.

```
POST http://localhost:11235/form/upload HTTP/1.1
....
Content-Length: 40
Content-Type: multipart/form-data
file: C:\fakepath\swagger.json
text: 123
```

The file content is not transferred in the request. Only the file name is written into the request. Is this because swagger editor does not support file upload or my swagger json is wrong? Could anyone kindly help me with this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is still an open issue for swagger-editor:
https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-editor/issues/599

as reported it has been fixed in swagger-api:
https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/838

Use swagger-ui for file uploading, it is working:

```
- in: formData 
  name: document
  description: Documento Fiscal
  required: true
  type: file
```